# How do you draw a DFA for a specific range of binary numbers?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa

I need to learn how to design a DFA that accepts binary strings in a specific range.

A question states that each octet in an IP address is made up of 8 bits and they each represent a positive integer from 0 to 255 inclusive. I am then asked to **draw a DFA to accept binary representations of all octets in the range 119 to 231**, over the alphabet {0, 1}. It could be any given range, but what are the steps to working a question like this out?

Comment: Something to think about: can you solve the following more general problem? Given a fixed list of strings w_1, ..., w_n, design a DFA that accepts just w_1, ..., and w_n and nothing else?

Comment: @templatetypedef i do not, could you help out with a general solution to such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main categories of approach:

1. Enumerate every string, then using a DFA-minimization algorithm to find a reasonably-sized solution. This only works when the language is finite, like your example.
2. Generalize from known properties of the language, and build your DFA directly. Sometimes starting with an NFA is conceptually easier, which you can then algorithmically convert to a DFA.

For your example, let's try both approaches. For either approach, we want to see what the strings look like.

```
(119)10 = (01110111)2
(120)10 = (01111000)2
...
(230)10 = (11100110)2
(231)10 = (11100111)2
```

Going with approach 1, you start with a DFA with 9 states, 8 transitions, linearly.

```
start -0-> q1 -1-> q2 -1-> q3 -1-> q4 -0-> q5 -1-> q6 -1-> q7 -1-> [q8]
(q8 is an accepting state)
```

This accepts the string `01110111`. Now, add on what we need to accept `01111000`:

```
start -0-> q1 -1-> q2 -1-> q3 -1-> q4 -0-> q5 -1-> q6 -1-> q7 -1-> [q8]
                                    |
                                    1
                                    V
                                   r5 -0-> r6 -0-> r7 -0-> [r8]
```

This DFA accepts `01110111` and `01111000`. You can keep doing this, and you'll eventually get a really complicated hydra-like DFA that has a different accepting state for every word in the language. You can then run a DFA-minimization algorithm to shrink it down.

Going with approach 2, think about the structure of the words in the language. and categorize them, if possible, into groups with similar structure. For example, any string starting with `10` of length 8 will be accepted (these are the numbers between 128 and 191). So you can match all of them with a simpler DFA:

```
start -1-> q1 -0-> q2 -0,1-> q3 (etc until [q8]).
```

Finding a few categories of similarity like this will help reduce the number of branches you have to consider.